# Paypal Item Title Prefix

Tags: paypal

In the information transmitted to Paypal for payments, Civi adds a prefix to the "Item Title".

E.g. Donations through the "Donations" contribution page have a Paypal Item Title such as this: 603-607-Donations.

Is there any way to stop the prefix from being included? It's interfering with our use of the PayPal reports and sorting donations according to the source (contribution page).

Answer (score 1):

Not through the UI i guess. You can make use of the https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterPaymentProcessorParams/ in your extension and have something like -

```
$params[`item_name`] = 'your custom title';
```